# EJB 3.0 JNDI lookup (Weblogic 10.x)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jndi, weblogic-10.x

I use weblogic 10.3.6 and so EJB 3.0. I have EJB and local interface. Both packaged in ejb-jar inside ear.

```
@Local
public interface TestLocal {
...
}

@Stateless
public class TestEJB implements TestLocal {
...
}
```

To access this EJB from war I have in my `web.xml`

```
<ejb-local-ref>
  <ejb-ref-name>ejb/TestLocal</ejb-ref-name>
  <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
  <local>testpackage.TestLocal</local>
</ejb-local-ref>
```

And lookup looks like

```
test = (TestLocal) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/TestLocal");
```

Everything works fine. Now I need to call this EJB from the same ejb-jar where it packaged. But I have `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException` all the time. What I have already tried:

1. In `ejb-jar.xml` in ejb-jar (not ear)

   ```
   <ejb-name>TestEJB</ejb-name>
   <ejb-local-ref>
     <ejb-ref-name>TestEJB</ejb-ref-name>
     <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
     <local>testpackage.TestLocal</local>
     <ejb-link>myjar.jar#TestEJB</ejb-link>
   </ejb-local-ref>
   ```

and following lookups

```
 initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/TestEJB");
 initialContext.lookup("TestEJB");
```

2. in `weblogic-ejb-jar.xml`

   ```
   <weblogic-enterprise-bean>
    <ejb-name>TestEJB</ejb-name>
    <jndi-name>TestEJB</jndi-name>
    <local-jndi-name>TestEJB</local-jndi-name>
    <enable-call-by-reference>True</enable-call-by-reference>
   </weblogic-enterprise-bean>
   ```
3. Both `weblogic-ejb-jar.xml` and `ejb-jar.xml`

Have you any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you use JNDI at all when looking it up within the same application? You only need to inject it via @EJB.

Comment: I ca't use @EJB because I need reference from POJO

Answer (score 0):

JNDI in Java EE has different namespaces. Prior to Java EE 6, there is typically only the "global" namespace and the "component environment" namespace.

Each EJB has it's own component environment. A webapp also has it's own component environment. This is what you're looking up when you use a JNDI name prefixed with `java:comp/env`. Objects are added to the component environment via deployment descriptors (ejb-jar.xml and web.xml):

```
    <ejb-name>TestEJB</ejb-name>
    <ejb-local-ref>
         <ejb-ref-name>TestEJB</ejb-ref-name>
         <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
         <local>testpackage.TestLocal</local>
         <ejb-link>myjar.jar#TestEJB</ejb-link>
    </ejb-local-ref>
    ...
```

So, from within the *calling context* of TestEJB, you would lookup the reference above:

```
  TestLocal testLocal = (TestLocal) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/TestEJB");
```

The JNDI lookup name is always `java:comp/env/<ejb-ref-name>`.

You can see this actually looking up another instance of itself, because that is what you have declared above. *It's possible this is not what you intended.*

Given the above, the answer to your question depends upon the calling context of your POJO.

If it is webapp -> POJO -> TestEJB, then you should use the webapp's component environment and lookup "java:comp/env/ejb/TestLocal".

If it is webapp -> SomeEJB -> TestEJB, then you need to add a component environment to SomeEJB (not TestEJB as you have in your example) and lookup the name that you define there.