# How to access an EJB in an ear from a war?

Tags: ejb, weblogic, war, ear

I have two Projects deployed on the same weblogic server:

1. An ear archive with an EJB (@Local, @Stateless)
2. A war archive

I want to access the EJB from a class inside the war archive. Is this generally possible? How?

Comment: The short answer is yes, you can. Which version of Weblogic are you using?

Comment: The weblogic version is 10.3.6.

Comment: Take a look at [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889496/ejb-3-0-jndi-lookup-weblogic-10-x) and also at [this Oracle discussion thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2441337?tstart=0).

Comment: Thank you but in the examples the EJB will called from the war inside the ear, which contains the EJB. In my case I have two separated and independend deployments - an ear and a war. How I have to fill the <ejb-local-ref> entry in the web.xml in the war in my case?

Comment: Try the following: `<ejb-local-ref><ejb-ref-name>ejb/MyEJB</ejb-ref-name><local>my.ejb.package.MyEJBLocal</local></ejb-local-ref>`. Then, to look it up, you should access `java:comp/env/ejb/MyEJB`.

Comment: I insert this in that web.xml, which is in the seperated war, not in that war inside the ear. I get this error: EnvironmentException: [J2EE:160200]Error resolving ejb-ref 'ejb/MyEJB' from module 'web' of application 'myapp'. The ejb-ref does not have an ejb-link and the JNDI name of the target bean has not been specified. Attempts to automatically link the ejb-ref to its target bean failed because no EJBs in the application were found to implement the 'testpackage.myLocaleIF' interface. Link or map this ejb-ref to its target EJB and ensure the interfaces declared in the ejb-ref are correct.

Comment: The `ejb-link` is missing. Add the following to your `ejb-local-ref` structure: `<ejb-link>my-ejb.jar#MyEJBInterface</ejb-link>`.

Comment: No sry, it does not work: weblogic.deployment.EnvironmentException: [J2EE:160167]The module web in application MyApp uses ejb-links but no EJB modules were found for this application. Btw, my Interface and my real ejb-class are in different jars.

Comment: And you're only providing a `@Local` interface, no `@Remote`?

Comment: Yes. But I think this cannot work. Where in this solution is the connection from the war-deployment to the ear-deployment included the ejb? I think the JNDI name of the EJB should be "java:global/ear-filename/ejbjar-inside-ear-filename/ejb-classname" (java:global/app-name/modul-name/bean-name). But my calling class inside the war archive does not find the EJB by this name.

Comment: The thing is that Weblogic does not make local interfaces available on the global JNDI tree. That's why you can't access it through the `java:global` lookup.

Comment: Is it possible to make the local Interface explicit available on the gobal JNDI tree, perhaps with the deployment descriptor of the ejb-jar inside the ear? And means the global in java:global as much as: All applications deployed in the same domain of a single application server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Interface needs @Remote
2. Stateless annotation of EJB class needs mappedName = "ejb/myEJB"
3. Lookup with "ejb.MyEJB#mypackage.MyEJBInterface"